# Estimating memory usage of Cocos2d game

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I am using Cocos2d 2.0 with ARC enabled. My game is a random generated game so I need to load/unload textures( spritesheet-batchnode) within a scene in the middle of the game. I am trying to removespriteframesfromfile and remove texture for key for a spritesheet that i wish to unload in the middle. When I use dumpcachedtextureInfo after unloading the sheet, that spritesheet texture doesnot show up in the logs of dumpcachedtextureinfo.

But when I use Instruments/activity monitor to profile my app, the real memory usage doesnot drop after unloading the texture and spritesheet.

Is there a way where dumpcachedtextureinfo will not show a texture that is still in memory?
Also, My livebytes column in allocations shows 4 MB.

Also as i read at various places that allocations doesnot show texture memory.

So my allocations live bytes column says 4 MB, my total texture memory as shown with logs of dumpcchedtextureinfo is shown to be 84MB, but memory monitor stills shows real memory usage to be 84+Spritesheet size+ Live Bytes

I am not able to understand this difference?

I am not exiting the scene, so I am not sure if ARC is holding the memory or what?

Comment: Since you're already using Instruments, check if any of the big chunks of memory are still "living" and perhaps leaked. Other than that, perhaps you were looking at the total allocations column which will never decrease.

Comment: I am concerned about the "Real Memory usage" metric under activity monitor. It doesnot decrease at all even after unloads. I cant understand why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Some useful notes for you

- [This Cocos2d memory optimisation](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/) explains very well about memory management in Cocos2d.
- To check total memory allocation use: Instrument->Activity monitor.

[image]

[image]

- To check memory leaks use: Instrument-> Leaks
  [image]

Comment: I have already gone through that link and yes it is very helpful. My problem is not optimisng memory. My problem is knowing the exact memory used by my app at an instance of time.

Comment: in instrument you can see...hope u know :-

Comment: also: select allocations, object list. Search for class name (ie CCTexture2D). If there's a dot next to it, it's still living (in memory). See if that changes when removing texs from cache.

Comment: I checked with allocations-objectlist-cctexture2d.
I see the stack trace of a live object created under cctextue2d object. There I can see the method where I loaded the spritesheet. Real Memory shows me the total size including the textures i am unloading and the ones that dont show up in dumptexturecacheinfo.

While using ARC is it enough to release the textures? If I am not exiting the scene , how is ARC deallocating stuff? I am inside game scene.This started after I enabled ARC and migrated to ARC. What is it that I might be missing?

Comment: If I create few sprites and animations, and run some actions on them. Later In the game , I need to unload the texture that has these sprites, I removechild these sprites, removeanimationbyname and remove the texture. Is there any thing more that I need to do to unload?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D  I tried whateveris suggested above. Please help me figure out what is the  problem